# How to find/replace with regex in Sublime Text between two H3 tags?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have 250 blocks of HTML list items, and I need to remove specific lines between `<h3></h3>` tags.

The lines (including h3, li, a) that need to be removed will contain "USPS".

```
<ul>
   <h3>
      <li><a href="medicine/Alabama/Birmingham">Medicine in Birmingham, AL</a>
      </li>
   </h3>
   <h3>
      <li><a href="/shampoo/Alabama/Birmingham">Shampoo in Birmingham, AL</a>
      </li>
   </h3>
   <h3>
      <li><a href="/usps/Alabama/Birmingham">USPS in Birmingham, AL</a></li>
   </h3>
   <h3>
      <li><a href="/snacks/Alabama/Birmingham">Snacks in Birmingham, AL</a></li>
   </h3>
</ul>
<ul>
   <h3>
      <li><a href="/medicine/Arizona/Mesa">Medicine in Mesa, AZ</a></li>
   </h3>
   <h3>
      <li><a href="/shampoo/Arizona/Mesa">Shampoo in Mesa, AZ</a></li>
   </h3>
   <h3>
      <li><a href="/usps/Arizona/Mesa">USPS in Mesa, AZ</a></li>
   </h3>
   <h3>
      <li><a href="/snacks/Arizona/Mesa">Snacks in Mesa, AZ</a></li>
   </h3>
</ul>
```

I have tried using regex, but it's removing too much. I have a saved link here for the latest regex attempt: https://regex101.com/r/l4Ud4v/1

`(?s)<h3>.*USPS.*?<\/h3>`

Desired results:

```
<ul>
   <h3>
      <li><a href="medicine/Alabama/Birmingham">Medicine in Birmingham, AL</a>
      </li>
   </h3>
   <h3>
      <li><a href="/shampoo/Alabama/Birmingham">Shampoo in Birmingham, AL</a>
      </li>
   </h3>
   <h3>
      <li><a href="/snacks/Alabama/Birmingham">Snacks in Birmingham, AL</a></li>
   </h3>
</ul>
<ul>
   <h3>
      <li><a href="/medicine/Arizona/Mesa">Medicine in Mesa, AZ</a></li>
   </h3>
   <h3>
      <li><a href="/shampoo/Arizona/Mesa">Shampoo in Mesa, AZ</a></li>
   </h3>
   <h3>
      <li><a href="/snacks/Arizona/Mesa">Snacks in Mesa, AZ</a></li>
   </h3>
</ul>
```

There are 250 of these "USPS" instances that need to removed while preserving the rest of the HTML.

Comment: Ideally, use the approach exhibited in The fourth bird's answer for things like this, especially if you work on large texts. Specificity is key here (i.e. telling the regex engine exactly what kind of strings you expect structurally) since a) you have repetition of the exact same structure anyway and b) you want to fail quickly in substrings that you're not interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
(?s)<h3>(?:(?!</h3>).)*USPS.*?</h3>
```

https://regex101.com/r/AB6wxS/1

Even non-greedy `(?s)<h3>.*?USPS.*?</h3>` will fail because it'll match at the first `<h3>` and then consume until it finds USPS, matching over the closing tags. To avoid that you can do `(?:(?!</h3>).)*` which basically says match any char as long as it's not the start of `</h3>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have that specific formatting for all the lines (with h3, li, a), and you want to match them in Sublime:

```
<h3>\s*<li>\s*<a\b[^<>]*>[^<>]*\bUSPS\b[^<>]*</a>\s*</li>\s*</h3>
```

The `\s*` matches optional whitespace characters, and `[^<>]*` is a negated character class that matches any character including newlines, except for `<` and `>`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TIIMBI/1).